# Best way to derive a MAC key without a salt

Tags: key-derivation, salt, nonce

- It's best to use separate keys for encryption and the MAC.
- Most implementations tend to derive a larger key and split it in two (e.g. scrypt with an output of 32 + 64 = 96).
- Alternatively, you can generate one key and then use HKDF to generate a subkey for the MAC key.

**How can you derive a MAC key using the encryption key without a salt? Or how can you derive a salt (for HKDF) given an encryption key and a nonce?**

I know you can use HKDF without a salt but a) that's not as strong and b) I want the MAC key to be unique despite the same encryption key.

Lets say I want the user to only pass in an encryption key and a random or counter nonce.

Comment: Are you using only the salt to generate the AES-GCM key with HKDF? What is the source of the nonce?

Comment: Lets assume the nonce is random or a counter.

Comment: Those are different, if counter, once a value of the counter is leaked all is lost! If uniform random, then you can use it as a key if it has already 128-bit uniformly random. AES-GCM doesn't need random nonces, it can use counter based.

Comment: You can use a counter nonce with GCM.

Comment: That is what I said! I think your only question is what if my random source has a weak entropy, how can I generate a secure key?

Comment: My question is whether the nonce can be used as a salt in some scenarios.

Comment: You don't want to run a KDF from the encryption key. You'd want to run it from a master key and then derive an encryption key and a MAC key from that master key, possibly using a salt. If you'd use a salt at that time then both the encryption and MAC key are randomized and you don't need a nonce anymore; you can just set it to all zero. Note that scrypt also generally uses a salt; using a second salt is then not really needed.